# Can't see fonts that are properly placed

Tags: fonts

I've just transferred most of my configurations on to this new laptop. I3 works just fine, along with the rest of the software. However, I can't seem to use my fonts!

I placed them first directly into `/usr/share/fonts`, ran `xset +fp, mkfontscale`, `mkfontdir` and `fc-cache -f -v`. I can't see anything but the standard fonts in URxvt, and i tried to use a GUI program, Gedit, without seeing them there either.

I continued on, after researching this a bit, to place the same font files in `~/.fonts`, as well as `~/.local/share/fonts`, and did the same procedure of commands. Doing `xset +fp` in `~/.fonts` I got:   `xset:  bad font path element (#0), possible causes are...`

Still can't see the fonts in either URxvt or Gedit. Could somebody suggest what I'm supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use the fonts placed in `~/.fonts`, although you need to place the `*.ttf` files there for the corresponding fonts.

Use `lxappearance` for using the fonts, you can choose the fonts right from the drop down menu in this program. In case of a few friends though, I found that your fonts may not be listed in the menu, in that case you will need to edit a few files in order to apply the fonts everywhere in the system. The steps you need to take then are :

1. Open `lxappearace`
2. Choose any font from the list and hit apply. This will create certain `*.config` files which you can then edit to use the desired fonts as your GTK fonts.
3. Now in the following files at appropriate place change the name of the font to the one you want.

The files you'll need to edit

1. `~/.gtkrc-2.0`
2. `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`

I got to know about this method from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARKIwOlazKI&t=316s).

Now you should be able to use the fonts of choice every where in the system.